# Azure DevOps - Yaml pipeline publish release status to work item

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

First - I know that according to the official MS documentation the built in functionality for updating work items with release status via the deployment control is only supported in the release pipelines and not the multi stage YAML pipelines (see first note documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/work-item-deployments-control?view=azure-devops)

Has anyone used powershell or the Azure DevOps rest api's to create an addon or integration that can update the work item with the correct information to automate the linkage of work items to the release environment information given that this functionality doesn't appear to be available for the yaml release pipelines?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The Deployment field is not supported by Yaml Pipeline. This feature is only for Release Pipeline.

If you want to link Yaml Pipeline to Work item, it can be linked as Build type.

[image]

To achieve this in YAML pipeline, you can try to use the Task: WorkItem Updater task
from [WorkItem Updater](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BlueBasher.bluebasher-workitemupdater)

```
- task: WorkItemUpdater@2
  displayName: 'WorkItem Updater'
  inputs:
    workItemType: xx
    workitemLimit: xx
    linkBuild: true
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks good to know on the linking on the build, however still want a solution to the release status

Comment: @RobertLamberson were you able to figure out any solution for linking yaml release pipeline with work item? If yes, can you please give some suggestions?