# Is there a way to show on an Azure Board if there's a new build on a specific Pipeline, and if it built successfully?

Tags: azure-devops

It can be either as a thing that appears in a Work Item on the Azure Board, or as anything else. As long as it will appear on the Board consistently, it is helpful :)

[image: Image depicting an example board]

I'd expect something that can show up either on the Board cards, or when you click on the Work Item, that will tell me that there's a new build, and if it built successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automatically link work items to builds refer to the following steps.

1. Link work items when you create a branch, commit, or pull request. Take linking to the work item when creating a commit as an example. Select your target work items from **Work item to link**.

[image]

2. Go to pipeline settings. Check **Automatically link work items included in this run**.

[image]

3. Then you can see the build and its state in the target work item.

[image]

See [Automatically link work items to builds or releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/configure-pipelines-work-tracking?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#automatically-link-work-items-to-builds-or-releases) for the detailed info.

If you only want to monitor the state of a pipeline, you can use the widgets in the Dashboard.

1. Use [Build history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#build-history-widget:%7E:text=builds%20and%20releases.-,Build%20history,-Adds%20a%20tile). As shown below.

[image]

2. Use [Team Project Health](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.TeamProjectHealth). Take "Build Health Details" for example.
   [image]

Comment: I'll talk with the developers if its possible for them to link the work item. I'll consider using that widget too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can update or create a work item using the `az devops` cli quite easily from a pipeline, so if you wanted to you could add a final step to the pipeline to create a work item with the correct field values to have it show up on a board.

And [then there is the Development Work and Deployment controls on the work items where you can track the status of the builds and deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/add-link?view=azure-devops#deployment-control). This only works if the work item was correctly linked to a commit and the commit is correctly linked to a CI build and the CI build then subsequently links to a deployment.

[image]

Unfortunately, this feature only works with Classic Release Pipelines out of the box. You do need to enable this in the pipeline's settings:

[image]

[There are extensions that enable this functionality on YAML pipelines as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69023451/736079).

Comment: Unfortunately the pipeline is a YAML pipeline, and the extension you provided is not approved by the organization, so none of these really help me. But thank you for input!

Comment: You could probably replicate the functionality in the extension with a few API calls scripted in PowerShell.